# Interpolation for continuous data in R

Tags: r, dataframe, interpolation

I have a sample data as follows:

```
data1 <- read.table(text="1/1/12 1:48 AM  1.24
1/1/12 8:14 AM  0.26
1/1/12 2:01 PM  1.15
1/1/12 8:25 PM  0.15
1/2/12 2:36 AM  1.23
1/2/12 9:13 AM  0.25
1/2/12 2:54 PM  1.09
1/2/12 9:17 PM  0.16
1/3/12 3:28 AM  1.24
1/3/12 10:06 AM 0.21
1/3/12 3:52 PM  1.07
1/3/12 10:05 PM 0.15
1/4/12 4:21 AM  1.27
1/4/12 10:56 AM 0.16
1/4/12 4:49 PM  1.08
1/4/12 10:52 PM 0.12
1/5/12 5:12 AM  1.32
1/5/12 11:43 AM 0.1
1/5/12 5:41 PM  1.12
1/5/12 11:37 PM 0.08
1/6/12 5:58 AM  1.38
1/6/12 12:28 PM 0.03
1/6/12 6:27 PM  1.17
", sep="", header=F)

    > head(data1)
      V1   V2 V3   V4           date
1 1/1/12 1:48 AM 1.24 1/1/12 1:48 AM
2 1/1/12 8:14 AM 0.26 1/1/12 8:14 AM
3 1/1/12 2:01 PM 1.15 1/1/12 2:01 PM
4 1/1/12 8:25 PM 0.15 1/1/12 8:25 PM
5 1/2/12 2:36 AM 1.23 1/2/12 2:36 AM
6 1/2/12 9:13 AM 0.25 1/2/12 9:13 AM
```

#### Combine 3 columns to one to make data column

```
data1$date <- paste(data1$V1, data1$V2, data1$V3)
```

#### Create a date sequence to do the interpolation

```
daterange <- seq(from=as.POSIXct("2012-1-1 00:00"), to = as.POSIXct("2012-1-6 00:00"), length.out =1200)
```

I want to find the corresponding V4 values of the daterange specified above. I want to do the linear interpolation.

Comment: Are you sure you want linear interpolation? Your data does not seem to be linear at all...

Comment: The data I have listed here is tidal data i.e high tide and low tide. I want to join these points and find the points in between them. For example the data on first row is high tide data and second is low tide. The major thing to do right now is to find points between each rows. Can you suggest what interpolation technique is more suitable here ?

Comment: You could try and have a look at cosinor analysis or maybe autoregressive models (ARMA or ARIMA). If you just want to calculate the point between a high and a low (and not go into prediction) you just need the arithmetic mean.

Comment: Just keep in mind that your data is most probably too undersampled for any interpolation to really make much sense...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have said, you can use `approx(...)` to interpolate between successive points, although it's debatable if this is a good idea.

```
data1$posix <- as.POSIXct(data1$date,format="%m/%d/%y %I:%M %p")
df <- as.data.frame(with(data1,approx(posix,V4,n=1200)))  # colnames are "x", "y"
colnames(df) <- c("date","V4")
df$posix     <- as.POSIXct(df$date,origin="1970-01-01")

library(ggplot2)
ggplot()+
  geom_point(data=data1, aes(x=posix, y=V4), color="red", size=5)+
  geom_point(data=df,    aes(x=posix, y=V4), color="blue", size=1)+
  labs(x="Date")
```

[image]

Note the format string in the call to `as.POSIXct(...)`. You have to specify that the times are in 12hr format using `%I` (not `%H`), and you have to specify that the string contains AM/PM (using `%p`), or your character times will not convert correctly. (They *will* convert, though, without throwing an error - so be careful).

Comment: Thank you jhoward for explaining all the details. Yes, it is debatable as it might not be a good idea. This might be helpful for me in future too.